# Is it possible to activate coverage in jest but not printed it in console?

Tags: jestjs, jest-preset-angular

Coming from Karma I like to keep a browser tab opened to check the code coverage of my tests from time to time. Is possible with a jest to generate the coverage folder **without** jest printing the coverage in the console?

I have not found out any cli or config about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set up `coverageReporters` config for jest like this:

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  coverageReporters: ['json', 'lcov', 'clover']
};
```

By default, the value of `coverageReporters` configuration is `["json", "lcov", "text", "clover"]`

As you can see, if you don't want to print the coverage report in stdout, you need to remove `text` reporter.

Before:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/53934331/authService.spec.ts
  authService
    #postAuthUser
      ✓ login user (6ms)

----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File            |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 authService.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.703s
```

After:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/53934331/authService.spec.ts
  authService
    #postAuthUser
      ✓ login user (5ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.64s
```